# Color effect for headlines

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create a function that takes a headline and calculate its word length to divide it into 3 separate spans.

Each of the spans would get a unique style applied to it.

example:

```
<span style="color:red">Hea</span>
<span style="color:blue">dli</span>
<span style="color:green">ne</span>
```

any help to achieve this effect instead of doing it manually would be wonderful.

Comment: Those colors are invalid by the way. Either choose hex or written implementations

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `substr` function combined with `.html()`.

```js
headline = "Terminator";
sub = Math.floor(headline.length/3);
first = headline.substr(0,sub);
second = headline.substr(sub,sub);
third = headline.substr(sub*2);

$("<span style='color:red'>").html(first).appendTo("body");
$("<span style='color:blue'>").html(second).appendTo("body");
$("<span style='color:green'>").html(third).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Surely this doesn't answer the question as this is based on character length not word length as specified in the question?