# Split Dynamic Content headlines into two colours within WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, dynamic

A site I'm designing in WP has a running theme for the headers, where the first half of the heading one colour and then the second half with an accent, with static headlines this is easy to do with a span tag i.e.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>This Is <span>My Headline</span></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {color:#1f7b76;}
span {color:#75b482}
```

But with Title's that are dynamic I'm not sure how I can make this work inside of the WordPress frame work.

I looked at this answer but I don't think this would work with WordPress the way it's required [Color effect for headlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312227/color-effect-for-headlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with the following which seems to do what you need:

```php
$title = "My absolutely amazing WordPress post!";

$title_array = explode( " ", $title );

function addSpanToTitle( $t ) {

    $word_count = count( $t );

    if ( $word_count % 2 == 0 ) {

        $half = $word_count / 2;

    } else {

        $half = ceil( $word_count / 2 );

    }

    $result = "";

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $word_count; $i++ ) {

        if ( $i < $half ) {

            $result .= $t[ $i ] . " ";

        } elseif ( $i == $half ) {


            $result .= "<span>" . $t[ $i ] . " ";

        } elseif ( $i > $half ) {

            if ( $i == $word_count - 1 ) {

                $result .= $t[ $i ] . "</span>";

            } else {


                $result .= $t[ $i ] . " ";

            }
        }

    }

    return $result;

}

echo "<h1>" . addSpanToTitle( $title_array ) . "</h1>";
```

To use this in WordPress, you can define the function in your themes `functions.php` and do something like this in your templates:

```php
<?php $the_title = explode( " ", get_the_title() ); ?>

<h1><?= addSpanToTitle( $the_title ); ?></h1>
```

[image: This is the result]

Essentially what this function does is takes in an array - your title that has been *exploded* - and then figures out the halfway point, then adds an opening `<span>` before the word at the halfway point (rounded up) - if your title is 6 words long, the last 3 words will be inside the span, if your title is 5 words long, the span will enclose the last two words.

At the end of the title, the span is closed. This is returned from the function as a string. The function is all you need from this script, the rest of the code has been added so you can copy and paste and see how it works with various strings.

This can definitely be improved upon and written more concisely, but this seems to do what you need, albeit not perfectly.

---

Here's a revised version of the function that takes the title as a string:

```php
function addSpan( $title ) {

    $title = explode( " ", $title );

    $half = count( $title ) % 2 == 0 ? count( $title ) / 2 : ceil(count( $title ) / 2 );

    $result = "";

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $title ); $i++ ) {

        if ( $i == $half ) {

            $result .= "<span>" . $title[ $i ] . " ";

        } elseif ( $i == count( $title ) - 1 ) {

            $result .= $title[ $i ] . "</span>";

        } else {

            $result .= $title[ $i ] . " ";

        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

Usage:

```php
<h1><?= addSpan( get_the_title() ); ?></h1>
```

Comment: As you went to so much trouble and I can;t give you more upvotes here I'll upvote some of your other answers :)

Comment: @GibsonFX very much appreciated, it was actually pretty fun to write, I may use it myself! Really glad I could help :D

Comment: Can I ask instead of rounding up how would I get it to round down?

Comment: @GibsonFX `floor()` instead of `ceil()`

Comment: I'm testing on a 2 word title, ceil doesn't seem to be adding the span at all, and floor seems to be adding the span after the two words <h1 class="two-color-heading">Residential Care<span> </span></h1> Any ideas?

Comment: Okay I just tried with a 4 word title and the same thing is occurring too

Comment: Try this instead, think I messed up; `<h1><?= addSpan( get_the_title() ); ?></h1>`

Comment: `the_title()` echos the title, `get_the_title()` returns it. That was sloppiness on my part.

Comment: Perfect, works now, that could have been a real headache, I was assuming the issue was in the function part, I was about to start tweaking bits to see if I could work it out, I probably would have spent hours going in circle lol Thank you so much for your help :)